# SQL Server: DB STARTUP blocking processes

Tags: sql-server, database, recovery

I am trying to run

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE
```

(or `CHECKDB`, same result), but I keep getting this error:

> Check statement aborted. Database contains deferred transactions.

I've made some researches and found that it's some process with SPID 5 and command DB STARTUP blocks everything. This process is running for a few days already but neither `dbcc opentran` nor `dbcc inputbuffer(5)` show anything.

Looks like it just sits there and does nothing.

I've checked the logs for that database and it seems that recovery process went fine (last records are about step 3 of 3 running and that over 500K transactions were rolled back so I assume it's done)

I've tried some advice from Google but none of them helped. Setting database to `SINGLE_USER`, `EMERGENCY` and even `OFFLINE` changed nothing - actually, all of them were blocked in one way or another. I can't restore it from earlier backup for some reasons, and there is no more good advice in Google.

Please help.

Comment: Can you restart the SQL Server Service?

Comment: You  may get better assistance with this question on the dba stackexchange site.

Comment: which sql edition?

Comment: Restarted SQL Server. Recovery seems went fine again, despite now I have 2 DB STARTUP processes, one of them is blocked by another. Also database is now inaccessible saying something like "Lock timeout, error 1222"

Comment: Reboot the server.